# getting a value from a csv file, looking at the database, getting the id of the record that matches the value

Tags: php, mysql

OK folks, here's a fun one for you.

So our back office system has all the cruise fares in it and we've made a nice little script that allows the back office system's export of the fares to import into the website.

It's a neat script, except... the back office system exports the cruise code e.g. P210 and the website's database has a fares table which contains each fare as record, connected to the relevant cruise by a 'cruise_id'

So the cruise table is something like this

id title code departs..... etc etc

and the fare table is like this

id cruise_id fare offer... etc etc

Works great on the site, but the back office export doesn't know the unique id of the cruise on the website.

So is it possible, after we have uploaded the csv file, before it inserts, to look up the cruise_id from the cruises table using the code, and use that in the insert query ?

Here's the upload script so far

```
<?php
 require_once('includes/connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $filename=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen("$filename", "r");
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {

       $import="INSERT into fares_usa(cruise_id, active, type, category, placement, deck, fare, offered, status, sortorder) 
       values('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[5])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[6])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[7])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."',
       '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[9])."')";
       mysql_query($import, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
     }
     fclose($handle);
     print "Import done";
   }
   else
   {

      print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='fileupload.php' method='POST'>";
      print "Select file to import:";
      print "<input type='file' name='filename' size='20'>";
      print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>";
   }
   ?>
```

I hope I have explained it ok...

Rich :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it... here's the code

```
<?php
 require_once('includes/connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $filename=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen("$filename", "r");
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {
         $lookup_cruise = mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);

    $query_cruiseid = "SELECT id FROM cruises WHERE code = '{$lookup_cruise}'";
    $get_cruiseid = mysql_query($query_cruiseid, $connection);
        $cruise_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_cruiseid);


       $import="INSERT into fares_usa(cruise_id, active, type, category, placement, deck, fare, offered, status, sortorder) 
   values('".mysql_real_escape_string($cruise_id['id'])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[5])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[6])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[7])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."',
   '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[9])."')";
   mysql_query($import, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
     }
     fclose($handle);
     print "Import done";
   }
   else
   {

  print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='fileupload.php' method='POST'>";
  print "Select file to import:";
  print "<input type='file' name='filename' size='20'>";
  print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>";
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm would not a before trigger do the trick? trigger "before insert on xy for each row" and then check "if new.cruise_id is null then select into cruise_id". Maybe you have to add an extra column for the code (P120) because the code is not a number like ID would be. to save space you can set the code columns value to null in the same trigger after lookup the id.

An seperate loader table or an insertable view (maybe) could also be an option.